# React alert Uncaught Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some problems with installing react-alert, it's showing error like

`react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

So I run command in cmd `npm install react-alert react-alert-template-basic react-transition-group`

This is how my App.js looks like.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';

import Header from './layout/Header';
import Dashboard from './leads/Dashboard';
import Alerts from './layout/Alerts';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

const alertOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    position: "top center"
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                    <Fragment>
                        <Header />
                        <Alerts />
                        <div className="container">
                            <Dashboard />
                        </div>
                    </Fragment>
                </AlertProvider>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And I have added component Alers.js and it looks like.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert';

export class Alerts extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.alert.show("It works");
    }

    render() {
        return <Fragment />;
    }
}

export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

So in Alert.js, I added componentDidMount() to test is this working (obviously not). 
And if I delete `<Alerts />` from App.js I don't have any errors but Alerts is not working in that way.

Comment: Can you try like `export default withAlert()(Alerts)`

Comment: Omg, thank you very much, I didn't saw that I forgot (). Works now!

Comment: You are welcome. Then let me provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should import your component like that in order to use `withAlert` HOC:

```
export default withAlert()(Alerts);
```